# Postgres SQL - Top 2 records GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count, top-n

I have a some data in the following format:

| Bus | Route |
| --- | --- |
| Slowcoach | SC123 |
| Slowcoach | SC123 |
| Slowcoach | SC123 |
| Slowcoach | SC555 |
| Slowcoach | SC555 |
| Slowcoach | SC555 |
| Slowcoach | SC555 |
| Slowcoach | SC111 |
| SpeedyTram | ST111 |
| SpeedyTram | ST111 |
| SpeedyTram | ST222 |
| SpeedyTram | ST222 |
| SpeedyTram | ST222 |
| SpeedyTram | ST222 |
| SpeedyTram | ST333 |
| SpeedyTram | ST444 |

I want to count the Routes and then show only the most popular 2, grouped by Bus :

| Bus | Route | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Slowcoach | SC555 | 4 |
| Slowcoach | SC123 | 3 |
| SpeedyTram | ST222 | 4 |
| SpeedyTram | ST111 | 2 |

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT Bus, Route, COUNT(Route) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Bus, Route
ORDER BY Bus, COUNT DESC
```

I have looked at Rank / Partition /Limit but I can't get the COUNT field to work, nor can I work out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group and count (`ti`) then order/assign position by bus (`tx`) and select these with position <= 2.

```sql
select bus, route, cnt
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by bus order by cnt desc) r
  from 
  (
    select bus, route, count(*) cnt 
    from the_table
    group by bus, route
  ) ti 
) tx
where r <= 2;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e78e/7)

The same using `ti` and `tx` as CTEs, maybe cleaner and more readable:

```sql
with ti as
(
  select bus, route, count(*) cnt from the_table group by bus, route
), 
tx as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by bus order by cnt desc) r from ti
)
select bus, route, cnt from tx
where r <= 2;
```

**Edit**
If you need the result with ties then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution a bit twisted :

```
  WITH list AS
    (
    SELECT Bus, Route, COUNT(Route) AS count
    FROM test
    GROUP BY Bus, Route
    ), consolidated_list AS
    (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(row_to_json(l.*) ORDER BY l.count DESC) AS list
      FROM list AS l
     GROUP BY Bus
    )
    SELECT j->>'bus' AS bus
         , j->>'route' AS Route
         , j->>'count' AS count
      FROM consolidated_list AS l
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query (l.list :: jsonb, '$[0,1]') AS j
```

Result :

```
bus         route   count
Slowcoach   SC555   4
Slowcoach   SC123   3
SpeedyTram  ST222   4
SpeedyTram  ST111   2
```

see details in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=72418d6774e956df542f13aa3cec7b8f)